# TYPO3 extbase database query

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I have an extbase database query like below.

```
$query = $this->createQuery();        
$result = $query->statement("Select * FROM table1 WHERE hidden = 0 AND deleted = 0 AND (".$PublicationYears.") AND logo != '' ORDER BY uid ASC LIMIT 0, ".$iLimit." ")->execute();             
return $result;


$PublicationYears = "ttra = '12' or ttra = '13' or ttra = '14'";
```

I converted this query as follows,

```
$query = $this->createQuery();

$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);

$query->matching( $query->logicalAnd(
       $query->equals('deleted', 0),
       $query->equals('hidden', 0)
    ));

$query->matching($query->logicalAnd($PublicationYears));

$query->matching($query->logicalNot(
     $query->equals('logo', '')
 ));

$query->setOrderings(array('uid' => Tx_Extbase_Persistence_QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING));

$query->setLimit((integer)$iLimit);
$Result = $query->execute();

return $Result;
```

But the resultant query does not contain the query part related to,

```
$query->matching($query->logicalAnd($PublicationYears));
```

I think there are also other mistakes in the above query.

Please help me to create correct query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

first of all you dont need this

```
$query->matching( $query->logicalAnd(
   $query->equals('deleted', 0),
   $query->equals('hidden', 0)
));
```

`disable fields` are included in query from default according to setting of table in ext_tables.php

multiple matching will not work
cause your third matching

```
$query->matching($query->logicalNot(
 $query->equals('logo', '')
 ));
```

is overwriting the `matching()` used before it
`logicalAnd` on string ? it won't work either

in your case you just need to put everything in `logicalAnd` do it like this

```
$constraints = array();
$subConstraints = array();
$subConstraints[] = $query->equals('ttra', 12);
$subConstraints[] = $query->equals('ttra', 13); 
$subConstraints[] = $query->equals('ttra', 14);
$constraints[] = $query->logicalOr($subConstraints);
$constraints[] = $query->logicalNot(
     $query->equals('logo', '')
 ));

$query->matching($query->logicalAnd($constraints));
```

Answer (score 0):

For your PublicationYears values you have to make or query in matching like below:
I think it might work only for PublicationYears variable.

```
 $query->matching($query->logicalAnd(
            $query->logicalOr(
                $query->equals('ttra', 12)           
            ),
            $query->logicalOr(
                $query->equals('ttra', 13)           
            ),
            $query->logicalOr(
                $query->equals('ttra', 14)           
            ),
        ));
```